# error : multiple definition of constructor

Tags: c++

Can you please help me to know how I can avoid the error.. 
Thanks in advance.

file name: point.hh

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H
class Point{
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        Point();
};
#endif
```

file name:point.cc

```
#include "point.hh"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Point::Point()
{
    x=0;
    y=0;
    cout<<"x="<<x;
    cout<<"y="<<y;
}
```

file name: main.cc

```
#include"point.cc"
int main()
{
    Point p;              // calls our default constructor
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You must include the header file, not the source file, in your `main.cc` file to use the `Point` class.

That is, replace:

```
#include"point.cc"
```

By:

```
#include"point.hh"
```

The rationale behind this is that a function definition, unless marked `inline`, must respect the **ODR** ("One Definition Rule"). By including the source file in your other source file, you end up having two (identical) definitions of the `Point::Point()` function in two different translation units.

When the linking process takes place, it sees this two definitions and complains: that is the error you get.

Comment: how is this from the compilers point of view? I mean you try to compile with g++ main.cc point.cc and cpp main.cc and cpp point.cc both include definitions due to #includes right, and this is the underlying reason, right?

Comment: @Umut Tabak: I'm not sure to get you right, but yes, that's the reason. However, if the OP does not add the generated object file for `point.cc`, the link process should succeed because in this case, only one definition for `Point::Point()` would be found. Note that this would still be really crappy.

Answer (score 3):

Another cause is the build command, if you have the same .cpp file listed twice you will definitely get this error and it will say that functions you didn't even write have the error.

Might help someone in the future.